# Datorama Marketing Cloud Reports - Advanced

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-datorama

Does Marketing Cloud Datorama Reports offers the ability to query individual subscriber data inside SFMC? If yes, what is the range of customization one could get? Is it just basic sends, opens and clicks, or you can go more granular than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask two questions :)
Datorama Reports for Marketing Cloud exists in a basic and advanced version.

I can speak about the basic, free variant "Datorama Reports for Marketing Cloud" (so not the paid, "advanced" variant, and not Datorama as a full tool).

It's probably best to reach out to SF for a feature overview of the paid, "advanced" variant or Datorama as a complete additional tool.

With the free DRfMC variant you get nothing in terms of subscriber level drill downs, you get various aggregated dashboards that have two general filter options:

By BU or by campaign (meaning the marketing cloud feature, not Sales Cloud campaigns).

Push also has OS and App.

==

For email engagement you can then additionally filter on email names and subject.

For Push, additionally Push Send Name and Push Title.

==

For journeys all of the above, depending on channel, plus additionally journey name, journey activity name and journey version.